# How to pass parameters between two different components on two different community pages?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have two different community pages, and on each page I have different component. I need to pass value from first component to other on click. I already have an event which navigates to that other page. I tried with application event and didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've been doing this using well defined keys in sessionStorage:

```
// in your initiating component
sessionStorage.setItem('myValueToPassThrough', 'abc');
```

Then in the init handler of your second component add:

```
handleInit: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var value = sessionStorage.getItem('myValueToPassThrough');
    // you may also want to wipe it out - but be aware it then won't be there on page reload
    sessionStorage.removeItem('myValueToPassThrough');
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about localStorage too, but I don't know is it a good practice? Are you sure there is no other "more lightning" way? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't seen a more Lightning way for passing data between pages unfortunately. I'd recommend not to use localStorage because it's shared between tabs and persistent between sessions. sessionStorage is better suited.